# Windows Forms Panel control slowly creeping

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

So I'm working on a card maker for a TCG.  I seem to have encountered a very odd glitch and can't find a decent workaround.  I have several panels that contain various controls for determining the different variables of the card, like so:

[image]

However, I've noticed that if I go into the `Form1`.cs file and change code--any code at all, from adding/removing comments to deleting and restoring a semicolon--and then go back into the design view, the design view window goes black for a moment whilst it redraws everything, and then pops back into place...except that the right-hand side of various panels has been bumped to the left about 5 pixels.  It doesn't seem like much, but after multiple changes, multiple swapping back and forth between windows I get this:

[image]

...which of course is hideous and unusable.  For a long time I couldn't determine why some panels did it and others did not, but finally while reworking the `Keywords` tab you can see in the screenshot, it dawned on me that it was any panel that I have set to anchor both on the left and right hand sides of the parent control.  This is to allow the user to resize the window to their heart's content.  I currently have a kludge in place in which I modified `Form1.Load()` to hard-code the size of the affected panels.  This is of course entirely against the whole point of using a visual editor in the first place.

The hierarchy of the controls goes `Form1`->`SplitContainer`->`SplitContainer.Panel2`->`TabControl`->`StatsTab`->`StatsPanel`.  This unfortunately doesn't appear to be a code-based problem since I don't write any code to affect this.  The redraws apparently actually change the `StatsPanel.Size` property, and if I cycle back and forth I can watch it sloowly decrement.

So, does anyone know what might be wrong?  I don't like to jump to "oh Microsoft has a glitch in their editor" but I can't find anything else that I am doing or setting that could be causing it.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: This is hard to answer, since effects like those are often a problem caused by the very details of the control / panel nesting within the designer code. Best advise I can give you is that you try to remove any unneccessary panel / control container first and see if the effects vanish.

Comment: I can only offer my condolences, as I was using Infrgistics components at the time, and on several screens, several controls were slowly going down.  I was occasionally pulling them up again, and learned to live with it :(  --  I guess that some parts of the FORM were extracted into separate control just to get rid of that behavior...

Comment: IF your design permits you, then did you try `yourPanel.Dock = Dock.Fill` instead of anchoring? What happens then?

Comment: @AVIDeveloper problem with that is, I have other panels beneath this one, although I suppose that then begs the question if I really need the divisions...I may actually give that a shot.  Thanks.